# Converting written to numeric dates in R

Tags: r, date

What's the most elegant way to convert these example dates to numeric dates:

```
dates <- c("April 1, 2017", "June 27, 2017", "September 24, 2017")
```

I would like this as a result:

```
"01-04-2017", "27-06-2017", "24-09-2017"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `base`

```
as.Date(dates, format = "%B %d, %Y")
[1] "2017-04-01" "2017-06-27" "2017-09-24"
```

and then formatted

```
format(as.Date(dates, format = "%B %d, %Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "01-04-2017" "27-06-2017" "24-09-2017"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mdy` function of `lubridate` package to parse dates. Then use `format` to convert it to desired form.

```
library(lubridate)
format(mdy(dates), "%d-%m-%Y")
#[1] "01-04-2017" "27-06-2017" "24-09-2017"
```